# WindowsError : [Error 2] System cannot find the file specified (but only with Atom)

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python, and I searched a lot but didn't quite find the same issue elsewhere.

I have a function that removes quotes from csv files on a specified column, writes the result in a temp.csv and then makes the temp.csv replace the file.csv.
Except I have an error when renaming.

Here is the code

```
import csv
import os

dossier_racine = "D:\PROG\Lire CSV"
fichier_source = os.path.join(dossier_racine, "fichier.csv")

    def removeQuote(fichier_csv, numColonne, separ=separateur):
        fichier_temp = 'temp.csv'

        print "\nOuverture du fichier %s" % fichier_csv
        lecture_fichier = open(fichier_csv, 'rb')
        lecture_csv = csv.reader(lecture_fichier)
        ecriture_fichier = open(fichier_temp, 'wb')
        ecriture_csv = csv.writer(ecriture_fichier)

        print "\nRemplacement des quotes"

        # remplace la chaine dans chaque ligne
        for ligne in lecture_csv:
            ligne[numColonne] = ligne[numColonne].replace("'", "")
            ecriture_csv.writerow(ligne)

        print "\nFermeture du fichier %s" % fichier_csv

        # Fermeture des fichier_csv
        ecriture_fichier.close()
        lecture_fichier.close()

        # récupère le nom du fichier source
        nom_fichiercsv = os.path.basename(fichier_csv)
        # récupère le nom du dossier contenant le fichier source
        nom_dossier = os.path.dirname(fichier_csv)

        # Supprime le fichier source pour que le fichier temp le remplace
        os.remove(fichier_csv)

        # Renomme le fichier temp avec le nom du fichier source
        # Afin qu'il le remplace
        os.rename(os.path.join(nom_dossier, fichier_temp),
                  os.path.join(nom_dossier, nom_fichiercsv))

removeQuote(fichier_source, 6)
```

Everything works fine when running with powershell. But when I try running it with Atom, and the Script package, I get this error :

> WindowsError: [Error 2] LSystem cannot find the file specified

On the line :

```
os.rename(os.path.join(nom_dossier, fichier_temp),
              os.path.join(nom_dossier, nom_fichiercsv))
```

Is there something wrong ? If so, could you help me find it please ?

Thanks

Comment: You create the temp file in the current working directory then you attempt to rename the file in the `nom_dossier` directory, i.e. the one containing the original file. My guess would be that is the current folder when run from Powershell but not when run from Atom.

Comment: That was exactly it. Thanks for the quick answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make Duncan's answer more visible, I'll update here.

I was working in `D:\PROG\Lire CSV` but my `temp.csv` was created in the working directory, which was something different for Atom.

So, I just changed the location of `temp.csv` at creation, created it in `nom_dossier`.